# Ubuntu server: Apache2 virtual hosts not working

Tags: server, apache2

I am trying to build a website for a school project and currently running ubuntu 20.04.4 server on win11 Hyper-V.

This is the .conf

```
  1 <VirtualHost *:80>
  2     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  3     ServerName test
  4     ServerAlias www.test.com
  5     DocumentRoot /var/www/test
  6     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  7     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  8 </VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts output:

```
  1 127.0.0.1 localhost
  2 172.19.181.104 www.test.com
  3 # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
  4 ::ffff:ac13:b568    www.test.com
  5 fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  6 ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  7 ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  8 ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

lsof output for ports 80/443:

```
apache2         4637            root    4u  IPv6  40001      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2         5695        www-data    4u  IPv6  40001      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2         5696        www-data    4u  IPv6  40001      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

apache2ctl configtest output:

```
Syntax OK
```

I have activated *test.conf* and disabled *000.default.conf* as well as disabled *ufw* just in case.

When I make changes to the index.html file located in /var/www/test, they show on 172.19.181.104 and the actual domain I've listed does not work.

Any idea why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your IPv6 record for the domain in `hosts` is pointing to `::1`. You may want to update that to point to the proper IPv6 value associated with `172.19.181.104` 

Comment: I noticed that too and have fixed it, but it still does not work.

Comment: Can you define “does not work”? Is the request reaching the server but not being processed? Is the request not going to the server at all? Do you see a different page? 